# Unable to Install Scrypt Due to Npm Install Crash

Tags: node.js, macos, node-gyp, scrypt

I am unable to run my Node express server because there is failure with downloading and installing script. I am on Mac OS 10.4.14. I want to be able to download the latest scrypt library.

I have tried removing the .node-gyp directory, removing the node_modules and building from scratch, and tried various versions of node from 12.3 to 11.x. I have also tried installing older versions of scrypt but fails with the same error. I have tried going to the github issue page for node-gyp but none of the suggestions worked for my situation: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809

```
node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/copied_files.node
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/util/memlimit.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/keyderivation.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/pickparams.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_wrapper/src/scryptwrapper/hash.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/scrypt_wrapper.a
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/util/warnp.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/alg/sha256.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/libcperciva/util/insecure_memzero.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt_lib/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/scrypt_lib.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_common.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.cc:4:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_params_async.h:28:
In file included from ../src/node-boilerplate/inc/scrypt_async.h:28:
```

{...Shows various failures and warnings}

```
8 warnings and 7 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/scrypt/src/node-boilerplate/scrypt_params_async.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v12.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
+ scrypt@6.0.3
```

I expected the package to successfully be installed as it was working a few days ago, but I cant seem to get past the installation issues.

Comment: Please edit to include your mac OS version appropriately. 'Latest' might induce confusion down the road.

Comment: thank you, it is 10.14.4

Comment: Did anyone figure it out? I tried all versions of Node from 12-19. I am still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been encountering a similar `node-gyp` error while building a docker container from the `node:12` image. At this time the only solution I have discovered is downgrading to `node 10.x`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried nvm down to 10.x, but it didnt change the outcome.